# Saying 'In my opinion, the internet has more good points than bad points'. [Comparative]

Tags: particles, syntax, comparative-constructions

To say 'In my opinion, the internet has more good points than bad points', would the following phrase be correct;

「僕のいけんでインタネットは悪い点よりもっといい点があります。」

Would this phrase be correct? Or would it make more sense to omit 「もっと」from the phrase. Or is the phrase entirely incorrect?

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> 「僕のいけんでインタネットは悪い点よりもっといい点があります。」

This sentence, while it would be understood by at least half of all native speakers, is not grammatical.  Here is why.

「もっといい」 can only be correctly used when making a comparison between "good things" and "even better things".  That is いい vs. もっといい.  That, however, is not what you want to talk about this time.  You want your sentence to make a comparison between the number of "good things" and that of "bad things".

Thus, the phrase you would like to use is:

> 「悪い点よりいい点の方が多い」 by using 「多い」, which means "to exist in larger numbers".

The whole sentence should look like:

> 「僕のいけんで**は**、インタネットは悪い点よりもいい点の方が多いです。」

To make it a little more natural, you can say:

> 「僕の意見{いけん}では、インターネットは悪い点よりもいい点の方が多いと思います。」 by using 「思う」.

Finally, to avoid sounding immature for using words like 「悪い点」 and 「いい点」, you can say:

> 「僕の意見では、インターネットは短所{たんしょ}よりも長所{ちょうしょ}の方が多いと思います。」